# XCB File Watching?

Tags: xcb, file-watcher

I starting work on a file watching mechanism. On *nix systems it is looking to me kqueue, libnotify, and GioFileWatcher are my only solutions - https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html

It is a big task so I wanted to verify before I got started. XCB doe not deal with file system is this correct? So file watching via XCB is not a possibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a rather short answer, but:

> XCB doe not deal with file system is this correct? So file watching via XCB is not a possibility?

Correct.

Comment: I totally understand, thanks Ingo, this is just what I was looking for. I couldn't find a concrete answer out there probably because it was so obvious to the XCB community. Thanks!